# C#: Getting correct length of string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to do string comparisons - I know it's not best to do so, but I need to for this solution.

If I were parsing a line such as: `Raiden: HelloWorld`, I would want to extract the separate strings `Raiden` and `HelloWorld` for further use.

**I currently do achieve this** by performing the following:
`var list = channelMessage.Split(' ', ':', '\n', '\0');`

However, when printing the result and length of each item in `list` the `HelloWorld` string's length is incorrect.

```
Output:
Raiden | length: 6
HelloWorld | length: 11
```

`HelloWorld`'s length should be 10, not 11. I'm assuming there's null characters somewhere in the line, but cannot figure out how to remove them all.

Sidenote: If I remember correctly, c#'s strings are arrays, and the last character of the array is a '\0' but I tried removing it (as seen above)

Is my assumption correct, and how can I correctly get `HelloWorld`'s length to 10?

Comment: I think you could just use `Split(':')` and then just `Trim()` all the items in the resulting list...  Really no need to split on all those other characters.

Comment: Have you tried .trim()?

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for the quick fix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're supposed to use `Trim()` to remove whitespaces around a string
See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8

This would result in

```cs
var list = channelMessage.Split(':').Select(s => s.Trim());
```

I'm also using the `Select()` from linq. This code would be similar to:

```
var list = channelMessage.Split(':');
var list2 = new List<string>();
foreach(string s in list)
    list2.add(s.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you split `Raiden: HelloWorld` on : you end up with this:

```
Raiden
_HelloWorld
```

Where the _ represents an empty whitespace.

Here's one possible solution. When I run this console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = "Raiden: HelloWorld";
    List<string> split = test.Split(':').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(split[0].Length);
    Console.WriteLine(split[1].Length);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I get:

```
6
10
```

Answer (score 0):

`Split` will likely give you trouble in this solution since it doesn't handle a huge range of input.

Something like a regex might be better because of the char ranges, something like `\W+` would match any non-world sequence.

example:
`Regex.Split("asdadaSD asdsad asdsad \n asdasdsd", "\\W+")`